# file STRINGS file "/opt/intel/mkl/include/mkl_version.h" cannot be read

Tags: python, opencv, ubuntu, cmake

For Python 3.4.3, Ubuntu 14.04, CUDA 8 and latest version of OpenCV download from opencv website and the following command:

```
(cv2) mona@pascal:~/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build$ cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..
```

I get the following error. Please suggest fixes.

```
-- checking for module 'libgphoto2'
--   package 'libgphoto2' not found
-- ICV: Downloading ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz...
-- ICV: Unpacking ippicv_linux_20151201.tgz to /home/mona/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv...
-- ICV: Package successfully downloaded
-- found IPP (ICV version): 9.0.1 [9.0.1]
-- at: /home/mona/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
-- CUDA detected: 8.0
-- CUDA NVCC target flags: -gencode;arch=compute_20,code=sm_20;-gencode;arch=compute_30,code=sm_30;-gencode;arch=compute_35,code=sm_35;-gencode;arch=compute_37,code=sm_37;-gencode;arch=compute_50,code=sm_50;-gencode;arch=compute_52,code=sm_52;-gencode;arch=compute_60,code=sm_60;-gencode;arch=compute_61,code=sm_61;-D_FORCE_INLINES
CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindMKL.cmake:32 (file):
  file STRINGS file "/opt/intel/mkl/include/mkl_version.h" cannot be read.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVFindMKL.cmake:72 (get_mkl_version)
  cmake/OpenCVFindLAPACK.cmake:10 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:559 (include)<!--

CMake Error at cmake/OpenCVFindMKL.cmake:90 (if):
  if given arguments:

    "VERSION_GREATER" "11.3.0" "OR" "VERSION_EQUAL" "11.3.0"

  Unknown arguments specified
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  cmake/OpenCVFindLAPACK.cmake:10 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:559 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Here's what exits at `cmake/OpenCVFindMKL.cmake` file:
http://pastebin.com/Yxq8GQTZ
Cmake log http://pastebin.com/JQSi2me3

Comment: Do you have intel MKL installed?

Comment: Thank you much Robert. Seems I had an older version of Intel MKL and the new version which I just installed solved the problem. I do really appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the latest version of Intel MKL and the problem should be solved. I had a way older version of it on my machine. Basically just download l_mkl_2017.0.098.tgz and type `sudo ./install.sh` and follow the dialogue with proper choices. It is an straightforward installation.

After success with cmake you should have a report similar to the following:

```
-- General configuration for OpenCV 3.2.0 =====================================
--   Version control:               unknown
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2017-01-19T02:54:29Z
--     Host:                        Linux 3.13.0-62-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       2.8.12.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 5.4.1)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wno-narrowing -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wno-narrowing -Wno-comment -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -msse -msse2 -mno-avx -msse3 -mno-ssse3 -mno-sse4.1 -mno-sse4.2 -ffunction-sections -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      
--     Linker flags (Debug):        
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         YES
--     Extra dependencies:          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so gtk-3 gdk-3 atk-1.0 gio-2.0 pangocairo-1.0 gdk_pixbuf-2.0 cairo-gobject pango-1.0 cairo gobject-2.0 glib-2.0 gthread-2.0 gstbase-0.10 gstreamer-0.10 gmodule-2.0 xml2 gstvideo-0.10 gstapp-0.10 gstriff-0.10 gstpbutils-0.10 dc1394 avcodec avformat avutil swscale vtkRenderingOpenGL vtkInteractionStyle vtkRenderingLOD vtkIOPLY vtkFiltersTexture vtkRenderingFreeType vtkIOExport dl m pthread rt /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so -lpthread -lm -ldl cudart nppc nppi npps cufft -L/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 cudev core cudaarithm flann imgproc ml video viz cudabgsegm cudafilters cudaimgproc cudawarping imgcodecs photo shape videoio cudacodec highgui objdetect ts features2d calib3d cudafeatures2d cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo java stitching superres videostab python2
--     Disabled:                    world
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 python3
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          NO
--     GTK+ 3.x:                    YES (ver 3.10.8)
--     GThread :                    YES (ver 2.40.2)
--     GtkGlExt:                    NO
--     OpenGL support:              NO
--     VTK support:                 YES (ver 6.0.0)
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.8)
--     JPEG:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (ver )
--     WEBP:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwebp.so (ver encoder: 0x0202)
--     PNG:                         /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (ver 1.2.50)
--     TIFF:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so (ver 42 - 4.0.3)
--     JPEG 2000:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjasper.so (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so (ver 1.6.1)
--     GDAL:                        NO
--     GDCM:                        NO
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394 1.x:                  NO
--     DC1394 2.x:                  YES (ver 2.2.1)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (ver 54.35.1)
--       avformat:                  YES (ver 54.20.4)
--       avutil:                    YES (ver 52.3.0)
--       swscale:                   YES (ver 2.1.1)
--       avresample:                NO
--     GStreamer:                   
--       base:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       video:                     YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       app:                       YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       riff:                      YES (ver 0.10.36)
--       pbutils:                   YES (ver 0.10.36)
--     OpenNI:                      NO
--     OpenNI PrimeSensor Modules:  NO
--     OpenNI2:                     NO
--     PvAPI:                       NO
--     GigEVisionSDK:               NO
--     Aravis SDK:                  NO
--     UniCap:                      NO
--     UniCap ucil:                 NO
--     V4L/V4L2:                    NO/YES
--     XIMEA:                       NO
--     Xine:                        NO
--     gPhoto2:                     NO
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Use IPP:                     9.0.1 [9.0.1]
--          at:                     /home/mona/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx
--     Use IPP Async:               NO
--     Use VA:                      NO
--     Use Intel VA-API/OpenCL:     NO
--     Use Lapack:                  YES (/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so /opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so -lpthread -lm -ldl)
--     Use Eigen:                   YES (ver 3.2.0)
--     Use Cuda:                    YES (ver 8.0)
--     Use OpenCL:                  YES
--     Use OpenVX:                  NO
--     Use custom HAL:              NO
-- 
--   NVIDIA CUDA
--     Use CUFFT:                   YES
--     Use CUBLAS:                  NO
--     USE NVCUVID:                 NO
--     NVIDIA GPU arch:             20 30 35 37 50 52 60 61
--     NVIDIA PTX archs:
--     Use fast math:               NO
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        <Dynamic loading of OpenCL library>
--     Include path:                /home/mona/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Use AMDFFT:                  NO
--     Use AMDBLAS:                 NO
-- 
--   Python 2:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python2.7 (ver 2.7.6)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython2.7.so (ver 2.7.6)
--     numpy:                       /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.11.1)
--     packages path:               lib/python2.7/dist-packages
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /home/mona/.virtualenvs/cv2/bin/python3.4 (ver 3.4.3)
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:
--     ant:                         /usr/bin/ant (ver 1.9.3)
--     JNI:                         /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include
--     Java wrappers:               YES
--     Java tests:                  YES
-- 
--   Matlab:
--     mex:                         /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014b/bin/mex
--     Compiler/generator:          Not working (bindings will not be generated)
-- 
--   Documentation:
--     Doxygen:                     /usr/bin/doxygen (ver 1.8.6)
-- 
--   Tests and samples:
--     Tests:                       YES
--     Performance tests:           YES
--     C/C++ Examples:              NO
-- 
--   Install path:                  /usr/local
-- 
--   cvconfig.h is in:              /home/mona/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/mona/computer_vision/opencv-3.2.0/build
```

Answer (score 2):

On an Ubuntu 12.04 machine, the latest MKL version I downloaded (l_mkl_2017.3.196) required Ubuntu 14.04, so Mona's solution did not work in this case.

What worked for me is adding an `if` to opencv-3.2.0/cmake/OpenCVFindMKL.cmake after line 71:

```cmake
set(MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS ${MKL_ROOT_DIR}/include)
if(NOT EXISTS "${MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS}/mkl_version.h")   # added these 3 lines
    mkl_fail()                                       #
endif()                                              #
get_mkl_version(${MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS}/mkl_version.h)
```

This is a simplified version of the ["official" fix for the issue](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/8042/files).